# Usage of oni + si in one sentence

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

How it will be right to use this combination? I mean some phrase like *Se mia foresto ne ŝanĝas ion en onia vivo, tiam mia ĉeesto en sia vivo ne gravas*. How can I note that *(sia) vivo* in the second case is the same that *onia vivo* in the first case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *sia* in the second part of the sentence doesn’t work, because it always refers back to the subject of the part of the sentence containing the verb, and in this case the subject is *mia ĉeesto*.

According to [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/pronomoj/tria.html#i-pkb), *oni* has two meanings, either it can refer to any person in general, or a specific set of hypothetical people. It also says that the general case is more common. I guess therefore one solution could be just to repeat *onia* in the second part of the sentence. However, in that case it’s not totally clear whether the second *onia* refers to the general case or the same set of people as in the first case. It could mean something along the lines of “if my presence isn’t important to *some* people, then it isn’t important to *anybody*”.

I think you could work around this ambiguity by using *ies* and *ties* instead:

> Se mia foresto ne ŝanĝas ion en **ies** vivo, tiam mia ĉeesto en **ties** vivo ne gravas.

Comment: You should think _oni_ as the _man_ passive in German/Swedish/Danish/Norvegian, i.e. any person(s) in general. Since _oni_ doesn't refer to any specific group of people, you can't assume that in _onia + onia_ the latter _oni_ would refer to the same people as the first one. So you would get something like Neil already said: some + anybody.

Neither can't you have _onia + ties_, because there is no specific group to which _ties_ could refer to.

The best solution is _ies + ties_ as Neil suggested.